# gnuplot: 2D plot of a matrix of data

Tags: gnuplot

How can I plot (a 2D plot) a matrix in Gnuplot having such data structure, using the first row and column as a x and y ticks (the first number of the first row is the number of columns) and represent the rest of the values by a colour mapping so it can be seen on a 2D plane ?

```
4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8
1 -6.20 -6.35 -6.59 -6.02
2 -6.39 -6.52 -6.31 -6.00
3 -6.36 -6.48 -6.15 -5.90
4 -5.79 -5.91 -5.87 -5.46
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can plot this data format using `matrix nonuniform`.

To get a heatmap you can plot either `with image` (regular grid, no interpolation, one quadrangle for each data point), or splot `with pm3d` (supports also irregular grids and interpolation, plots one quadrangle for four neighboring data points.

1. `with image`

   ```
   set autoscale xfix
   set autoscale yfix
   set autoscale cbfix
   plot 'data.dat' matrix nonuniform with image notitle
   ```

[image]

2. `pm3d`

   ```
   set autoscale xfix
   set autoscale yfix
   set autoscale cbfix
   set pm3d map
   splot 'data.dat' matrix nonuniform notitle
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thansk it worked. I have tried to do it with splot 'data.txt' with matrix , and it was giving me the number of columns and rows as indices.

Comment: No, "with matrix" simply is wrong syntax, "with" expects a plotting style. The trick for you data format is `matrix nonuniform`.

Comment: How can we include the data in the heatmap - each value of the data to be inserted in it's corresponding `(x,y)` position on the grid?

Comment: @Gathide Use the `labels` plotting style for this, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27049991/2604213

Comment: In such plot , always there are square of different colors. Can I get this same plot with points (circular points) of different colors ?